# How do I build app with :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets error?

Tags: javascript, android, typescript, react-native

I need help, I need to fix this error when building apk using `gradlew` `assembleRelease`, the configuration is successful, but when executing at 70% there throws an error:

```
> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets_SentryUpload FAILED
error: An organization slug is required (provide with --org)

Add --log-level=[info|debug] or export SENTRY_LOG_LEVEL=[info|debug] to see more output.
Please attach the full debug log to all bug reports.

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.
> Process 'command 'cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets_SentryUpload'.
> Process 'command 'cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

For info, I tried building without `bundleReleasejsAssets`, but when I install the app on my phone, App won"t start it is instantly crashing, just can't open, I think this `bundleReleaseJsAssets` needs to be added, or my app won't run.

Comment: Hi, any updates on this? I'm facing the same issue.